# Is it possible in SASS to inherit from a class in another file?

Tags: css, inheritance, stylesheet, sass

The question pretty much says it all.

For instance, if I were using, say, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), could I define classes in my own SASS stylesheet that inherit from Bootstrap's CSS classes? Or does inheritance in SASS only work within the scope of a single file?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

**YES!** its possible.

If you want all `<button>` elements to inherit the `.btn` class from [Twitter Bootstrap's Default buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)

In your `styles.scss` file you would have to first import `_bootstrap.scss`:

```
@import "_bootstrap.scss";
```

Then below the import:

```
button { @extend .btn; }
```

Comment: I feel bad for doing this since the other answers pretty much answered this question (I just neglected to check back for a while and then forgot); but I'm accepting your answer because it is the most complete—i.e., it walks me through the whole process. Thanks!

Comment: Does this only work with other SCSS files? Can you not do this with CSS files?

Comment: Be careful when you use `@extend` together with bootstrap/any framework, as it may not work as you expect. There are some things to be aware of as outlined in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744625/sass-and-bootstrap-mixins-vs-extends/30744854#30744854

Comment: But doesn't this duplicate the CSS from bootstrap.scss, if you do that in multiple files in your project?

Comment: Does this import the entire `bootstrap.css` into `styles.css` or just `.btn`? I mean in the output bundle? If it imports entire `bootstrap.css`, it will increase the size of `styles.css` unnecessarily.

Comment: The `@import` is not recommended anymore. From the project's page: "The Sass team discourages the continued use of the `@import` rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the `@use` rule instead."

Comment: extending another `@extend .classname` is also discouraged. SCSS is getting very confusing. :(

Answer (score 8):

**I might be mistaken, but if I get what you're trying to do, can't you just use the `@extend .classname;` command inside the element that you'd want to extend? Naturally, you should only modify your own code to preserve updatability.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, [you have to use `@import`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) of the file containing the classes you want to use into your SASS file in order to utilize them in that file. However, I am not a SASS/SCSS expert, so someone may know of another way to remotely use them that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the accepted answer has shown this is possible with @import, however @import has been [deprecated by sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

> The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead.

The @use rule is better suited for use now, since it does not pollute the scope of the importing (user) module. unfortunately at the time of writing the use rule is only implemented in Dart sass.

Comment: theres a dart sass compiler that compiles sass using @use just fine. But you have to target which file you want to compile in the settings or else all files will be compiled, even if you want to combine them in one file and only compile that one.