# Create new Twitter Bootstrap buttons with Bootstrap-Sass in Rails?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-rails, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to create new Twitter Bootstrap buttons in my Rails app so I don't have to override the old ones. Using the `Bootstrap-Sass` gem, I've figured out how to override the default buttons like so (to make the btn-warning class 'Twitter blue'):

```
$twitterBlue:#4099FF;
$btnWarningBackground: $twitterBlue; // (twitter blue)
$btnWarningBackgroundHighlight:     $twitterBlue;
```

I'd like to define a `btn-twitter` class, among others, but I can't seem to figure out how to copy all the Bootstrap styles into new buttons. I've tried things like:

```
$twitterColor: #4099FF;             // (twitter blue)
$btnTwitterBackground:              lighten($twitterColor, 15%);
$btnTwitterBackgroundHighlight:     $twitterColor;

.btn-twitter {
   background: $twitterBlue;
   // something goes here to inherit the base button styles
}
```

But that just makes a button with the default style.

I'm still fairly new to SASS and don't know much about the magic that's happening behind the scenes with the LESS -> SASS conversion. Also haven't been able to find anything on the 'net  about creating new buttons. If there's something out there, feel free to just point me to it :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**  While not perfectly related to the question, I figured I'd provide a super-handy link to the Bootstrap-Sass variable sheet which has helped me quite a bit with extending Bootstrap in my Rails project: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/templates/project/_variables.scss.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible in SASS to inherit from a class in another file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787330/is-it-possible-in-sass-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-another-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very possible you can achieve this using Sass's [`@extend` functionality](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

```
.btn-success {
  // some crazy unknown bootstrap stuff here
}

// in your file
.btn-twitter {
  @extend .btn-success;
  background-color: $twitterBlue;
  // more stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll look into it. Not having much luck so far, but I'll keep trying. Anytime I overwrite the `background` or `background-color`, it still keeps the green `btn-primary` style.

Comment: Have you tried the `!important` flag? `background: $colorName !important`.

Comment: That got me to changing the background color and the :hover background color, now I just need to figure out how to make it fade between the two like all the other Bootstrap buttons do.

Answer (score 11):

In Bootstrap 3.1, the default button looks like this:

```
.btn-default {
  @include button-variant($btn-default-color, $btn-default-bg, $btn-default-border);
}
```

You can use it the same way in your code, but note that this only works after the bootstrap import (unlike variable overrides, which must come first).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `button-variant` mixin that is already included in `bootstrap-sass`: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss#L6

For example:

```
.btn-secondary {
  @include button-variant(white, #F9622F, #d75124);
}
```

Additionally you can find other useful mixins like the ones listed in this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/5-useful-sass-mixins-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mixin file `_mixins.scss`

```
// Button backgrounds
// ------------------
@mixin buttonBackground($startColor, $endColor, $textColor: #fff, $textShadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25))
...
```

New custom Buttons are easy to create:

```
.mybutton{
    @extend .btn;
    @include buttonBackground($startColor:$bluelight,$endColor:$bluenormal);
}
```