# Is it possible to inherit from a Bootstrap class in LESS, using Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, less, extend

I'm building some custom [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) [button](/questions/tagged/button) classes in my Meteor app, using LESS. (Bootstrap is added to Meteor via the `twbs:bootstrap` Meteor package, rather than using `@import` in LESS).

For example, I have a class called `.btn-pill`, which I want to inherit from Bootstrap's `.btn-xs`, like this:

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-pill"></button>
```

LESS

```
.btn-pill {
    &:extend(.btn-xs);
    color: @text-color;
    background-color: @white;
    border: 1px solid @gray-main;
    &:hover {
        background-color: @gray-light;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work... Of course, I could always just use both classes in the `<button>` tag:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-pill"></button>
```

but I would rather avoid that if possible.

Is it even possible to use `&:extend` like this across different files (like I understand it does with `@extend`in SASS - like [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787330/is-it-possible-in-sass-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-another-file))? Or doesn't it work because Bootstrap is implemented via a Meteor package?

Comment: The only existing solution is https://atmospherejs.com/huttonr/bootstrap3. As you can see here https://github.com/huttonr/bootstrap3/blob/master/package.js, it uses the new build possibilities
(Package.registerBuildPlugin) to create your own version of bootstrap.

Comment: It's not a problem to use extend across different files. But those files should explicitly include the other (via `@import`) because otherwise the compiler just *can't* know anything about the rulesets you're trying to extend (i.e. in your example the compiler has no idea what `.btn-xs` is unless you import Bootstrap files. Exactly same way like in the Q/A you linked to).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I thought that would be the case indeed, but I couldn't find any source that confirmed that. Thanks for that!
Ser: thanks, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Meteor v1.2, less files are much more manageable.

Download official bootstrap less distribution, place them in a folder named `imports`. Doing this allows you to import files instead of seeing the compiled automatically.

Place the `bootstrap.less` file in a higher level folder outside the `imports` folder and fix the import folder paths according to your own structure.

Now you can use the variables to your liking. Do whatever with them that `less` normally allows you to do.

Or if you are stuck with Meteor's earlier versions, you can use [nemo64:bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/nemo64/bootstrap)  to customize and use imports from bootstrap.

Comment: The app I'm working on is still running an older version of Meteor (the update to v1.2 broke some things), but I'll give this a try as well...