# Is it possible to have a local class inherit all classes imported from a file?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss, css-modules

Say I have a css file that looks something like this:

```
/* Base styles */
.content {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .content {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

/* Headers */
h2 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Classes */
.small-caps {
    font-feature-settings: "tnum";
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
```

With PostCSS you can consume another class’s properties like this:

```
.another-class {
    composes: content from "other-file.css";
}
```

… which will be compiled to:

```
.another-class {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Is it possible to have a class inherit *all* styles from a given target so you can write something like (pseudo code):

```
.another-class {
    composes: * from "other-file.css";
}
```

… that when rendered it comes out like this?

```
/* Base styles */
.another-class .content {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--text);
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .another-class .content {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

/* Headers */
.another-class h2 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Classes */
.another-class .small-caps {
    font-feature-settings: "tnum";
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
```

Comment: I don't use bundlers or plugins often but are you talking about something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787330/is-it-possible-in-sass-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-another-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using Sass (Scss).

Example:

**test1.scss**

```
.elem {
  background: red;
  @import 'test2';
}
```

**test2.scss**

```
.inner {
  background: blue;
}

.outer {
  background: green;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  .something {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
.elem {
  background: red; }
  .elem .inner {
    background: blue; }
  .elem .outer {
    background: green; }
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    .elem .something {
      color: black; } }
```

Comment: I meant to include a “no sass” note but didn’t, so I’m going to mark your answer as accepted. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

yes it is possible. you can achieve this by using **SASS** like you have css.

```
.error {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background-color: #fdd;
}
.seriousError {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

and you can use it like

```
.error {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background-color: #fdd;
}
.seriousError {
  @extend .error;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

The @extend directive avoids these problems by telling Sass that one selector should inherit the styles of another selector.

Please refer to the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation) for more details.