# Import only one CSS class from another Sass file

Tags: css, sass

Consider this code:

```
// File A1.scss
.abc {
  // styles for abc
}

.def {
  // styles for def
}


// File B2.scss
.xyz {
  // styles for xyz
}
```

Is it possible to import and use `.abc` from `A1.scss` into `B2.scss` without having the class `.def` in `B2.css` (i.e. the output of `B2.scss`)?
`A1.scss` is large in real project, so can't afford to have `B2.scss` be bloated with other styles. I am using this in a React app with Webpack.

Comment: no, as far as i know this is not possible.

Comment: Maybe it helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787330/is-it-possible-in-sass-to-inherit-from-a-class-in-another-file

Comment: @DenizBayar: I already saw that post. In fact I have added this question in  comments on that post :).

Comment: You can move the common styles ( %abc { // styles}) into a separate partial and import that in necessary files. and use .class { @extend %abc ; }

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the relatively new sass rules - **@use** or **@forward**. Both rules only load the given .sass / .scss file **once**, even if used multiply in your project. Those two are part of **SASS Modules**. Both @use and @forward partially resolves one of the oldest css problems - **namespaces** and **private variables**.

```
// get ui/forms.scss file
@use 'ui/forms' as forms;

.footer-button{
  // use this specific mixin from ui/forms.scss
  @include forms.form-button;
}
```

More examples:

https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward/